# setting up a database for tracking which users have clicked which links?

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql

I'll try and elaborate on my problem a bit more.

I recently got an entry-level part time developer position with my university, in efforts to sharpen my dev skills. While I have used MySQL in the past, it was only briefly covered in a single course, as I am mostly a front end guy (HTML/CSS/JS).

Anyways, the department that hired me has a website designed for incoming students, to get them acclimated to college. It has tutorials and videos for them to watch, etc. In order to access the site, they must log in to their university account (which uses LDAP). Account names are in the format of abc1234.

Now, my problem is I need to create a way for the staff to track which tutorials/videos the freshman have watched. They would like me to do this using databases. There will potentially be thousands of students, and they want to be able to see exactly which students have / have not clicked each link/watched each video.

How should I set up databases for this? There will be multiple links/tutorials/videos that they want to track. Bonus points if there was a way of tracking which users watched the videos through to the end, however not required.

I believe I will need to use PHP for handling the exchange between the browser and the database, correct?

Thank you for any helps or tips. :)

Comment: Do you understand the relationships between a primary key and a foreign key?  If not you need to start with a relational database tutorial - http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/mysql-basics/ - But in short, you're going to end up with a table filled with students and a table filled with videos.  You will then have a third table that creates a relationship between students and videos commonly called a mapping table by linking the primary key of one to the primary key of another along with probably a date field and a bit field if it was completed.

Comment: This is way over a "front end designers" head. We have a team a 3 people and allocate about 4-6weeks to get a full tracking system like this wokring ( we track emails and what links were clicked from which email at what time and even where they went afterwards) You need to start with a generic handler to serve links from the DB, that somehow know which student it was and save it to another table. You need several tables and sql calls.

Comment: @RThomas: are that many tables necessary? I thought I could do this with a single table; 
*have and auto-incrementing ID, 
*the userID (from LDAP, they are all structured like abc1234)
*six columns to represent the video links

then whenever the user clicks a link, check to see if their ID is already in the table. If it is not, append it. Also append the current date and time to the link they clicked. Are primary/foreign keys necessary here?

Comment: If you can guarantee that there are only going to be six videos and there will never ever be more (or less), or other reports, statistics, that you might want to run, and you don't care about tracking if one video was watched more than once... then yes, you could do one table - it would basically be a spreadsheet.

Comment: @RThomas Out of curiousity, what complications would adding more links create? Wouldn't I just create another column to represent the new link? It would not need to be populated with any data, since it would become populated once the user clicks the new link. I'm not very familiar with databases but I don't see how this would prove to be worrisome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply make a PHP script that would retrieve the requested link for them, while also adding a value to MySQL.

If I were going to do this, I'd probably do something like this:

```
<a href="getResource.php?res=video1.mpg&type=video">Video 1</a>
```

And in PHP, I'd simply get the resource, type and the userid from the session, put them into the database, then retrieve the resource they were looking for. To track if they watched the video the entire way through, you could use javascript to watch for the event of the player coming to an end, then just use a skin that doesn't have a scrub bar.

Comment: hello,
this is exactly what I want to do. How do I retrieve the userID from the session? I can figure out the rest but that part I'm stumped on. After they've logged in with LDAP how can I retrieve their credentials for storing in my database?

Comment: I haven't done anything with LDAP in probably 5 years. I perused the  php manual for it, and assume you have [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php) code.
You'd need to start a session, and retrieve a username and password from the POST of the login script.

    `if ($ldapbind) {
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $ldapusername;
        header("Location: http://yourserver.com/page.php");
    } else {
        echo "login failed";
    }`

Then, you have your script simply grab the userid from `$_SESSION`, and use that to update your database. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: does session storage only work on a single page? I've set up a login page, and have gotten the connection to LDAP working correctly. I started a session and I set the session variables. Then I re-direct the user to the "tutorials" page. When I try and access the stored session variables here they are not set. How can I make the session vars persistent on the domain?

Comment: you need to use `session_start();` on each page. Declare it just after the `<?php`

Comment: Hi Wally, thank you for all the help! :) right now I have LDAP auth working, login working, session storage working. The only thing I have left to do is set up the database, and handle the database inserting when the user clicks a link. Do you have any recommendations for how I should structure the DB? Should I use one DB to store user ID and another to store what they've clicked on? There's only about 6 links we need to track but potentially hundreds of users we need to track. What do you think would be the best approach to this?

Thanks so much for all the help!

Comment: Since you're using LDAP to authorize your users, the DB would only be needed to track link clicks. You could do this in a number of ways, the simplest is probably the best.. One database with the userID as the primary key, and then a column for each link, and a simple boolean true or false (1 or 0) in each field, set the default to 0, and then I'd code the script to look for the user, if they don't exist, create a row, and add that they watched whichever video they watched.

Answer (score 3):

you need for example a table "users: id, name, etc..." and a table "clicks: user_id, url".

to track link clicks you could do something like this:

```
<a hreF="log_click.php?url=<?php echo urlencode("some_url?some=param&etc=anything"); ?>">
```

**log_click.php**

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['url'];
$user = /* ie. $_SESSION['user_id'] */
/* insert to database */
header('Location: '. $url); // maybe need urldecode($url) here
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply; The part I'm hazy on is what PHP I need to write to get the userID from LDAP. is it $_SESSION['user_id'] ?

Comment: ldap information does not autoamtically show up in the session variable. there are `ldap_*` methods in php

Answer (score 0):

Interesting project. You should extract the user from the current accesed page and store in a visited pages log (within the database) for each user.