# Tracking which webpage user is located(viewing)

Tags: php, javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [setting up a database for tracking which users have clicked which links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199521/setting-up-a-database-for-tracking-which-users-have-clicked-which-links)

I would like to know a way that I can keep track of user come in and out of my webpage, 
for example:
user come in to my website's "some_page", or exit my website's "some_page", or exit my website.

Perhaps i can set a variable in php to keep track of this? 
(Know exactly which page my user is located kind of idea)
Could you provide a method or code to tackle this action?

Comment: use google analytics to track info or any other tracking code. It actually depends what you want to track ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I just want to keep track of user coming in a webpage or leaving the webpage

Comment: I am trying to find a way to get started could you guys help me out here?

Comment: @RyanFung: use the search first, there are many question to that topic already, and as this has many angles, you should dig into the area first before asking such a broad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a query string on each page or set a variable. Like for example you have a var $urlId, then you pass a value Home.php...

```
                public function visitedPage()
                {
                    $urlId = 'Home.php'; 
                    if ($urlId)
                    {
                        $count = 1;
                        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
                        $page = array(
                            'page' => $urlId, 'ip' => $ip, 'count' => $count, 
                        );
                        return $page;
                    }
                }
```

You can save to your DB -> $urlID or the page.

You can save to your DB -> $ip of the user - which is u can determine the unique visitors etc... you can add additional function to that.

You can save to your DB -> $count... "edit this part". add additional function or method to automatically increment the count once the user visited again the site/page. You will know how many times he visited the page/site. You can determine if same user or not via IP.

Hope this little idea will help.

Comment: Exactly what i am looking for to get me going. Thanks a lot~